# Using newlib's malloc in an ARM Cortex-M3

Tags: arm, cortex-m, newlib

I'm creating code for an ARM Cortex-M3 (NXP's LCP17xx). I've been using static memory up to now and everything worked well.  I tried to add dynamic memory support, but once I call malloc, the system gets stuck.

I'm compiling with gcc for arm bare metal, and using newlib. Version: gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_6-2012q1

To add malloc support, I implemented a simple _sbrk function and modified my linker script to make some space for the heap (I've read many different tutorials about this part, but none cover the problem that I encountered next).

With the help of some leds, I can be certain that the code runs up until the point that it calls `malloc`, then it doesn't go on. It doesn't even reach my `_sbrk` function. Also, it will get stuck in a call to `sizeof`, if I include a call to `malloc` later on in the code.

So, what can I be doing wrong that when calling `malloc` the code gets stuck without ever reaching `_sbrk` or returning?

After staring for quite a while to the memory map generated when the `malloc` call is included and when it's not, I suspect that it's related to the structures that are used by `malloc`.

This is the part of the ld script that defines the ram memory:

```
.bss :
{
    _start_bss = .;
    *(.bss)
    *(COMMON)
    _ebss = .;
    . = ALIGN (8);
    _end = .;
} >sram
. = ALIGN(4);
_end_bss = .;
. = ALIGN(256);
_start_heap = .;
PROVIDE( __cs3_heap_start = _start_heap)

_end_stack = 0x10008000;
```

_end_stack is then set in the interrupt vector table.

And now a comparison of the different maps.  Without using malloc in the code:

```
 *(COMMON)
            0x1000000c                _ebss = .
            0x10000010                . = ALIGN (0x8)
 *fill*     0x1000000c        0x4 00
            0x10000010                _end = .
            0x10000010                . = ALIGN (0x4)
            0x10000010                _end_bss = .
            0x10000100                . = ALIGN (0x100)
            0x10000100                _start_heap = .
```

Memory map using malloc in the code:

```
*(COMMON)
COMMON      0x10000848        0x4 ...arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m/libc.a(lib_a-reent.o)
            0x10000848                errno
            0x1000084c                _ebss = .
            0x10000850                . = ALIGN (0x8)
*fill*      0x1000084c        0x4 00
            0x10000850                _end = .

.bss.__malloc_max_total_mem
            0x10000850        0x4
.bss.__malloc_max_total_mem
            0x10000850        0x4 ...arm-none-eabi/lib/armv7-m/libc.a(lib_a-mallocr.o)
            0x10000850                __malloc_max_total_mem

(...) It goes on (...)
            0x1000085c                __malloc_current_mallinfo
            0x10000884                . = ALIGN (0x4)
            0x10000884                _end_bss = .
            0x10000900                . = ALIGN (0x100)
            0x10000900                _start_heap = .
```

Comment: Are you sure you are invoking the startup code properly, which will initialize the heap structures?

Comment: I'm obviously doing something wrong, the problem is that I don't know WHAT I'm doing wrong. I've added extra info about the memory maps, hopefully will help to find the mistake.

Comment: A very similar problem happens when using sprintf.  So it's not just a malloc issue. It has to do with the whole newlib stuff.  It probably needs a change in the linking script, although I can't figure out what.

Comment: If it's in your budget, consider purchasing a license for an ARM compiler. Keil and IAR both make great ARM compilers that will take care of the vast majority of your toolchain issues and both have decent support.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So, after some 10 hours spent debugging this, I have finally made it work.  The problem was in the linker script. However, it was not in the bss section that I had posted, but in the text and data section.  Here's the script that works.

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-littlearm")
OUTPUT_ARCH(arm)
ENTRY(_startup)

MEMORY
{
    rom (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 512K
    ram (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH =  32K
}

/* Define the top our stack at the end of SRAM */
_end_stack = 0x10008000;

EXTERN(__interrupt_vector_table);

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        /* Insert the interrupt vector table first */
        __interrupt_vector_table = .;
        *(.interrupt_vector_table)
        /* Startup assembly */
        *(.startup)
        /* Rest of the code (C) */
        *(.text) *(.text.*) *(.glue_7) *(.glue_7t)
        *(.vfp11_veneer)
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
        *(.rodata) *(.rodata.*)
        . = ALIGN(8);
        _end_text = .;
        _start_datai = .;
    } >rom

    .data :
    {
        _start_data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data) *(.data.*)
        . = ALIGN (8);
        _end_data = .;
    } >ram AT >rom

    .data_init : { _end_datai = .; } >rom

    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx : { *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*) } > rom
    __exidx_end = .;

    .bss :
    {
        _start_bss = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(COMMON)
    } >ram 

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _end_bss = .;
    . = ALIGN(256);

    _start_heap = .;
    PROVIDE( __cs3_heap_start = _start_heap);

    /* Linker wants .eh_frame section defined because of gcc 4.4.X bug,
     * just discard it here. */
    /DISCARD/ : { *(.eh_*) }
}

_end = .;
PROVIDE(end = .);
```

I also had to add some variable initialization to my init code:

```
extern unsigned int _start_data;
extern unsigned int _end_data;
extern unsigned int _start_datai;
extern unsigned int _end_datai;

void init(void) {

    // (...) Other stuff

    // Initialize Global Variables
    uint32_t* data_begin  = (uint32_t*) &_start_data;
    uint32_t* data_end    = (uint32_t*) &_end_data;
    uint32_t* datai_begin = (uint32_t*) &_start_datai;
    uint32_t* datai_end   = (uint32_t*) &_end_datai;
    while(data_begin < data_end)
    {
        *data_begin = *datai_begin;
        data_begin++;
        datai_begin++;
    }
```

These two pages were quite helpful, although it still took me a lot to understand what was going on: http://fun-tech.se/stm32/linker/index.php and http://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/stellaris_arm_cortex-m3_microcontroller/f/473/t/44452.aspx?pi23648=1

I hope this might be useful to somebody else experiencing the same problems I was experiencing.

Comment: You also need to zero out the .bss section: `for(uint32_t* p = &_start_bss; p < &_ebss; ++p) *p = 0;`